# UISwitch not responsive in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'v encountered strange bug, and have no idea why this happens.

I have UIScrollView, in it I have 12 views. Most of them contain UISwitch button and a label. Size of views are dynamic (depending on the lenght of label.text). Everything works and shows, except two views on the bottom. They do get shown, initialize as expected. Yet UISwitches in them do not work, clicking or touching them does not do anything. Both of them are no exception to others (all of them are copy paste). I have double checked IBOutlets, they are fine. I have suspicion something is wrong with scrollView. Maybe beyond some point it doesn't recieve inputs anymore? Eventhough I can scroll up and down and everything is shown just as expected.

Any ideas what to check ?

I have switched these two views with first ones. And more bottom views get unresponsive, like there is a line, beyond which ui is not responsive. Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say the switch is in a view (one of 12) and that view is on the scroll view,
maybe the UISwitch is out of the view bounds?  Try to set that views `.clipsToBounds = YES;`, can you still see the switch?  If no, it means the switch is out of bounds therefor you gat no touch events.  Make that view larger to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check correctly. if the UISwitch and UIscrollview user interaction are enabled.
2. Check whether the UISwitch is added within the UIscrollview's frame.

Comment: Yes, both are user interaction enabled, and ui switch is inside scrollView frame. They do get shown, but there is no interaction between. It's just like there is a line beyond which no interaction can be made.

Comment: i am not sure. check there is any other views or any other objects of your 11 views added on the same frame. or Try to add that UIswitch in top of ur screen and check it out. if it is working means you should check any other view is added top of the UIswitch or not.

Comment: I'v got it working. One view in uiscrollview was big enough, and the bottom of that view lost user interaction for some reason. Spliting that view in to two views did the work. Thank you for your time looking into my problem